# Navigating latex packages for their options

Tags: fonts, formatting, package-options

I'm trying to find all the different font options available in the package devanagari for typesetting hindi. I found a template online, whose reduced working form is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Script=Devanagari]{mangal.ttf}

\begin{document}
Testing
\foreignlanguage{hindi}{बन्देश}
\end{document}
```

It seems to me that the font used is 'mangal.ttf' but how do I go about finding all the other font options available to me. I found the devanagari package on CTAN (link here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/devanagari) but I'm not sure how I can find a page with all the font options. I guess my question is how do I find the page that lists all the font options including 'mangal.ttf' and how they look?

Comment: You need a font viewer to find out which capabilities are built into an Opentype font such as `mangal`. One such program is [FontForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FontForge), which is available for several computing platforms.

Comment: @Mico Not necessarily. `otfinfo` is not a viewer, but it can tell you the features, supported scripts, available glyphs, font tables etc.

Comment: In your document, you are not using the `devanagari` package, are you? I think that what you want to know is which fonts, of those installed on your system, support Devanagari script? But I'm not sure if I've understood correctly: could you clarify your question?

Comment: @cfr I must admit that I'm not sure if I'm using the davanagari package. When I ran the code it installed many packages and I assumed one of them must have been {devanagari}

Comment: @cfr yes. I would like to obtain a list of the possible font types I can use with the devanagari script

Comment: You're using MiKTeX? With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? The code you posted does not use the `devanagari` package, which is not for use with those engines. (`polyglossia` depends on `fontspec` which requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if a particular font supports a particular script, you can use `otfinfo`:

```
otfinfo -s NotoSans-Regular.ttf 
cyrl            Cyrillic
grek            Greek
latn            Latin
```

To find out which fonts on your system support a particular language, you need to use some font management tool. Since you are using XeTeX/LuaTeX, you are able to use fonts installed for your system rather than just being restricted to TeX fonts. This is great as it improves support for non-Latin scripts dramatically. But it means that finding out what you have requires working with the tools available on your system.

On a GNU/Linux machine, for example, I can use `fc-list` to find fonts which support Hindi:

```
fc-list :lang=hi
```

But obviously this is dependent on your OS.